# BibLaTeX: how to specify two or more months in the "months" field

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to cite an article in a bimonthly journal. How can I specify two months in the months field in BibLaTeX so that my bibliography lists them both?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you have to use the date field.

Comment: @Bernard It works! If you want to answer the question with the solution I'll be glad to accept it, otherwise I can answer my own question (but it would not be fair, since you found the solution). I found the correct syntax for the `date` field on the biblatex manual, but I'm new to biblatex and I was unaware of the existance of that particular field, given the fact that there are `month` and `year`

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think it's necessary. I'm sure it's already in an answer (don't know where) and I have no example at hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex` expects a single month in the `month` field. You *could* input several numbers or something else entirely, but that will cause warnings, may not sort correctly and may not display as intended.

It is possible to input date ranges if you ditch `year`+`month` for the `date` field. Then you can use ISO 8601/EDTF input (see more about this in §2.3.8 *Date and Time Specifications*, pp. 39-40, of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date      = {1972-04/1972-05},
  journal   = {Hall Journal},
  volume    = {12},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {45-67},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Elk, Anne (Apr.–May 1972). ‘A Theory on Brontosauruses’. In: Hall Journal 12.3, pp. 45–67.]

---

Specifically for `@article` entries you could alternatively use the `issue` field. `issue` can contain arbitrary text and is printed next to the year (depending on the `mergedate` setting).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, mergedate=false]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  issue     = {Apr./May},
  journal   = {Hall Journal},
  volume    = {12},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {45-67},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Elk, Anne (1972). ‘A Theory on Brontosauruses’. In: Hall Journal 12.3 (Apr./May 1972), pp. 45–67.]